# PHP trigonometry TAN

Tags: php

I try to figure out an angle of a triangle.

If one side of the triangle is 100 and the other side is 100.

How do I get that to be 45 degrees.

If I run tan<sup>-1</sup>(100/100) on my calculator i get 45. How do I do this in PHP?

Comment: What exactly do you need then? That's pretty close to PHP already. PHP has a `tan` function.

Answer (score 3):

Use [the `atan` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.atan.php).

`tan-1(100/100)` on the calculator is the equivalent to `atan(100/100)` in Php.

**Edit: Sorry, here's the same output as the calculator:**

```
$input = 100 / 100;
print atan($input) * (180 / pi());
//Ouputs 45
```

Comment: I get 45 in my calculator and 0.78539816339745 with atan

Comment: @Daniel: Both are correct. One is in degrees and the other radians.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have both rise and run what you really want to use is [`atan2()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.atan2.php), which will handle the difference between e.g. 1/4*pi and -3/4*pi properly.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
$base = 100;
$perpendicular = 100;
echo rad2deg(atan($perpendicular/$base)); // 45
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$degrees = atan($tan);
```

[Source](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch02_12.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `atan2` from the math functions. This returns a value in radians though (by multiplying by 180 degrees over pi), so you also have to convert that to degrees. So something like this should work (also using the `pi()` function from the math library):

```
$degrees = atan2( 100, 100 ) * ( 180 / pi() );
```

Comment: There's also a built-in function for converting from radians to degrees: [`rad2deg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rad2deg.php).

Comment: @Viktor I have honestly never seen that. Learn something new everyday!